# Regex to Redirect all node urls to new homepage

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Take into consideration the following pages:

```
http://www.example.com/node/323
http://www.example.com/node/386
http://www.example.com/node/388
http://www.example.com/node/594
```

I would like to redirect all urls after the /node/ to a new homepage.

```
http://www.exmaple.com
```

Does anything have a .htaccess regex rewrite for something like this?

Comment: What did you try to resolve the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/node/.*$ / [L,R=307]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either mod_alias or mod_rewrite, but you should stick with mod_rewrite if you already have other rewrite rules, otherwise, mod_alias is simpler:

mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/node/ http://www.exmaple.com/
```

mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?exmaple\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^node/ http://www.exmaple.com/ [L,R=301]
```